# Adding foreign key Error 150

Tags: mysql

Ok look I know there are many questions out there about error 150.

But as SO says, " If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question."  so i am asking a new question.

I have two tables tableA and tableB, both engine are innoDB

My query `alter table tableA add foreign key (url) references tableB(url)`
gives `Error 1005 (HY000): can't create table myDatabaseName.#sql-3134 e52(error 150)`

So here's what i did.

```
alter tableA drop column url;
alter tableA add column url varchar(100) NOT NULL default "";
alter tableB drop column url;
alter tableB add column url varchar(100) NOT NULL default "";
alter tableB add primary key (url,bName,pID);

alter tableA engine = innodb;
alter tableB engine = innodb;
```

to confirm i checked `SHOW TABLE STATUS` both gave same innoDB engine

Then I tried again same query but same error.
So here's the situation so far

- both tables are using same engine
- both tables have compatible column url same datatype `varchar(100) NOT NULL default ""`

`show create table tableA` gives;

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
`url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`tNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
`bName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`pID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`oprNo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`found` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fix` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`fixStatus` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`fixDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`releaseStatus` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`releaseDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`url`,`tNo`),
CONSTRAINT `tableA_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`url`) REFERENCES `tableB` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

`show create table tableB` gives

```
 CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `pID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`url`,`bName`,`pID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**update**
I was able to add one foreign key url using mysql workbench
But same error is coming for other fields

```
 `alter table tableA add foreign key (bName) references tableB(bName)`<br>
 `alter table tableA add foreign key (pID) references tableB(pID)`
```

Comment: What if you run `alter tableB add primary key (url(100),bName,pID);`?

Comment: would you provide output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`? we need to check collation of table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create FK as belows:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD FOREIGN KEY (bName) REFERENCES tableB(bName);
ALTER TABLE tableA ADD FOREIGN KEY (pID) REFERENCES tableB(pID);
```

You should create `INDEX(bName)`, `INDEX(pID)` on tableB as follows:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE tableB\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: tableB
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `pID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`url`,`bName`,`pID`),
  KEY `bName` (`bName`),
  KEY `pID` (`pID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table tableA add foreign key (bName) references tableB(bName);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table tableA add foreign key (pID) references tableB(pID);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Didnt know the rule that for foreign key index is also needed although the column is already included in primary key !!!!

Comment: @HarendraSingh The problem is that your PK is composite index. Even tough `PK(a,b,c)` exists, searching by `b` or `c` cannot use index. I highly recommend that reading http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/WEBINAR-MySQL-Indexing-Best-Practices.pdf